# How to allow footnotes in frontmatter content in ConTeXt?

Tags: footnotes, context, context-mkiv, front-matter

I have a document structured like this:

```
\starttext
    \startfrontmatter
        \startstandardmakeup
            This is a title.\footnote{This is a footnote.}
        \stopstandardmakeup
    \stopfrontmatter
    \startbodymatter
        This is some text.\footnote{This is another footnote.}
    \stopbodymatter
\stoptext
```

After compiling, this creates a title page and page of text. The footnotes both get marks, "1" and "2", however, the footnote text for the footnote in the title page never gets printed. Is there any way to allow the footnotes to be displayed? They could appear on the title page itself or at least on the next page.

Comment: This has nothing to do with frontmatter. Footnotes do not work on makeup pages (as a makeup page is essentially a frame) You can try localfootnotes instead.

Comment: If you use `\automigrateinserts` the footnote appears on the page after the makeup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Aditya pointed out in the comment, the missing footnotes are unrelated to the
fact that you use a frontmatter. This works perfectly fine:

```
\starttext
  \startfrontmatter
    This is a title.\footnote{This is a footnote.}
  \stopfrontmatter

  This is some text.\footnote{This is another footnote.}
\stoptext
```

The makeup is the culprit. Local footnotes do work inside a makeup:

```
\starttext
  \startstandardmakeup
    \startlocalfootnotes
      This is a title.\footnote{This is a footnote.}
      \vfill\placelocalfootnotes
    \stoplocalfootnotes
  \stopstandardmakeup

  This is some text.\footnote{This is another footnote.}
\stoptext
```

Local footnotes, however, use an independent numbering scheme and
start from one and are not coupled to the global footnotes. They are
generally used for footnotes in tables.

Another solution is to use `\automigrateinserts`. This has the
advantage that the numbering is coupled with the global footnotes.
But the disadvantage is that the footnote appears on the next page.

```
\automigrateinserts
\starttext
  \startstandardmakeup
    This is a title.\footnote{This is a footnote.}
  \stopstandardmakeup

  This is some text.\footnote{This is another footnote.}
\stoptext
```